# Mold or rust stain on roof truss

Tags: roof, attic, mold, truss

Paid a visit to my attic earlier today to see if there was any winter damage.  Looking all good except for a small piece of truss that has a black stain on it (see picture).   I would have said mold but the symmetry of the stain is odd.   Could this be a rust stain or something else that was already present when roof was built?  If you look at roof sheathing nearby and cardboard piece preventing blow-in insulation from reaching soffit, it does not look like there was water infiltration anywhere nearby.

Looking for any input that you guys may provide.

[image]

Comment: what is winter damage?

Comment: I meant..leaks due to damaged shingles or ice dams.  Maybe even condensation cause by roof vents blocked by heavy snow.  Winters in Canada get nasty.

Comment: I think that is paint on the lumber, but if is that corrugated cardboard under it in the photo, I would get rid of that, as it can mold.  Hard to tell phone the photo exactly what it is and why it appears to be stapled to the lumber,

Comment: (How in the world did I type "phone" when I meant "from" in the above comment?  Mods, feel free to correct my comment!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Neither. It's labeling paint. It was either sprayed onto the entire lumber unit or this truss set for identification.

[image]
<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbidvenues.com%2Ffull-unit-studs%2F&psig=AOvVaw2F6tyTv1hk9JFS-YRDJeg6&ust=1619794957965000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKCWxczco_ACFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)</sub>

Comment: Are the dark marks on the ends of a few of those pieces of lumber burn marks from the rotary saw?

Comment: Or potentially, before being installed in the roof, that piece of wood was used to hold up something else that was being spray painted, and you're just looking at some over-spray.  Either way it's perfectly harmless.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket it's mostly natural variation in the wood.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you.  I was wondering why I rarely see it in wood I cut.  Probably just different species or variation of trees.